# Java mockito test method with void statements

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Below is my `AppleServiceImpl` class and a test class `AppleServiceImpl` which I created.
During my testing,

1. method `creditCheck` gets called
2. we call the class and method `appleService.creditCheck(request, response);` to test.
3. when credit check is called,the `appleHelper` object is null.doesnt get initalised.
4. How do I mock it or work around it to get testing done?

```
public class AppleServiceImpl extends GenericService implements ApplicationService {

    @Autowired
    AppleHelper appleHelper;

    public void creditCheck(ApplicationRequest request, ResponseMessage<ApplicationResponse> response) {
        appleHelper.test123(request, response);
    }
}

public class AppleServiceImplTest {
    @Spy
    AppleServiceImpl appleService= new AppleServiceImpl ();
    @Test
    public void creditCheck() {
        appleService.creditCheck(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't mocked the `AppleHelper` in the test

Comment: how do u do this?

Comment: what is your objective to test the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add a constructor to `AppleServiceImpl` that takes AppleHelper as a parameter and autowire on the constructor.
Next in your test you want to create an `@Mock AppleHelper appleHelper` field that you inject using `@InjectMocks`